# How does npm run build work with npm pack?

Tags: npm, npm-pack

I'm working on a project that requires using the `npm pack` command. Is running build on the library/package required before creating the installable tar file? Or can I just pack and then install it into the app?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but for totally different reasons.

- `npm run build` can do anything: it just executes the value for `build` inside the `scripts` object in your `package.json`, for example on an Angular project it'll look like this,

  ```js
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  ```
- `npm pack` basically *"create a tarball from a package"*, but here is the deal: the "package" that it creates a tarball from has to exist. So, in order to create the "package" that `npm pack` targets in `./dist`
  you frequently have to run `npm build`. This is because many JavaScript projects are written in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) (in which case "build" usually runs `npx tsc`) or use a build system that will transpile their code to produce JavaScript (like [babel](https://babeljs.io/)). If your project is very rudimentary, there is a good chance you won't have to "build anything": you can see this if you create an empty directory and run `npm init`, but seldom are useful packages created this way.

The result of `npm pack` is a `.tgz` file. This is basically a compressed copy of a target directory. You can install this with `npm i ./file.tgz`. On the consuming machine that you wish to install the package on, you do not have to *build* anything. Building is what you do as a developer and a package maintainer. For example, you build TypeScript producing JavaScript. The consumer just downloads the result and installs the dependencies. It doesn't even have to know that you write your code with TypeScript (or better, [Rust.](https://www.rust-lang.org/what/wasm))